# Limit textarea inner text width but not scrollbar

Tags: css, textarea, width, scrollbar

I have a textarea. It's limited by its container and stretched out to fit it perfectly. The problem I have is that I want to set a max-width to the text inside it, without affecting the scrollbar position.

If I set max-width to the textarea itself, the scrollbar moves from the right and more to the left.

### The working code, except for inner text limit

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

textarea {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  padding: 4rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<textarea spellcheck="false">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur est lectus, ornare eget purus in, lacinia eleifend lectus. Duis eu libero id sapien congue ultrices. Suspendisse eu quam sed risus congue placerat vel quis mi. Donec iaculis lorem sem, ac auctor nibh tempor et. Donec at facilisis eros. Proin semper tincidunt orci, vel eleifend nisl blandit ut. Suspendisse cursus posuere erat, et convallis mauris varius id. Suspendisse orci nulla, tempor a lorem non, ullamcorper condimentum ante. Aenean suscipit tortor in vehicula vehicula. Donec tincidunt, orci non scelerisque ornare, leo sem finibus sapien, ac faucibus sem tellus nec orci. In eu mi lacus. Ut mollis felis vitae sem molestie lobortis. Maecenas viverra, enim vel tempus vulputate, diam est vehicula nisi, non suscipit massa justo ac lacus. Nunc non laoreet quam.

Phasellus eget lacinia quam. Vivamus malesuada turpis a arcu hendrerit euismod. Fusce mattis purus ac ultrices aliquet. Donec ut tellus elit. Fusce eu imperdiet est. Duis feugiat enim massa, ut suscipit erat ornare a. Aliquam in viverra nunc, eget sagittis risus. Aenean vitae blandit neque. Donec consectetur nisi metus, quis vehicula dolor vestibulum vel. Nam sit amet ullamcorper dolor. Aliquam tincidunt velit imperdiet urna mattis, rutrum hendrerit tellus sollicitudin. Nulla blandit sem sed interdum sagittis. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.

Nullam pellentesque aliquam sollicitudin. Vestibulum nec molestie arcu, finibus cursus nisi. Sed efficitur vitae turpis sed volutpat. Aenean blandit tortor lectus. Suspendisse potenti. In mattis at risus vel varius. Praesent convallis arcu quis diam eleifend, vitae faucibus tellus dictum. Mauris volutpat finibus risus eget placerat. Proin ante elit, venenatis quis dapibus et, viverra eget velit. Duis consectetur dignissim magna, a pellentesque mi sagittis in. Phasellus sollicitudin, tellus ut mattis aliquam, eros nulla finibus arcu, ac ornare eros sem sit amet mauris. Praesent laoreet efficitur dolor, ut ultricies dui iaculis sed.

Maecenas consectetur, ligula a suscipit rhoncus, turpis lacus ornare turpis, at efficitur sapien metus vitae arcu. Ut et augue nulla. Phasellus a mauris bibendum velit lobortis venenatis. Sed laoreet aliquet velit at posuere. Nulla fringilla neque at velit tempor, eu fringilla eros vehicula. Suspendisse tellus elit, tincidunt a condimentum feugiat, ultricies rhoncus lectus. Curabitur ut purus eu nunc porta volutpat. Maecenas dignissim dui sed mi dapibus vehicula. Praesent porttitor bibendum velit, vel accumsan turpis consectetur vel. Donec dignissim nisl accumsan lectus posuere aliquam. Phasellus laoreet mauris non tellus vulputate pellentesque.

Donec sed aliquam metus, at malesuada tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam hendrerit quis ex sed efficitur. Quisque ornare consequat condimentum. Aliquam dapibus leo urna, a vehicula orci luctus et. Ut eget velit viverra, consectetur quam ac, pellentesque erat. Fusce dictum est ligula. Suspendisse tellus odio, imperdiet consequat aliquam vitae, elementum eu metus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</textarea>
```

### Tried with padding

I tried to solve it with padding. This code works, as long as the container is larger than 900px. Else the padding has no effect.

```css
padding-right: calc(100% - 900px - 4rem);
```

In the real code I have more elements at the sides of the textarea which means that I can't solve it with media queries or `vw`.

Comment: _“This code works, as long as the container is larger than 900px. Else the padding has no effect.”_ – it should not work if the element isn’t as wide as 900px _plus_ 4rem, because then you’d get negative values, and a negative padding isn’t possible. _“In the real code I have more elements at the sides of the textarea which means that I can't solve it with media queries or vw.”_ - so you basically would need _element queries_ – those aren’t a real thing yet, but there are several scripting solutions to try and emulate them, like f.e. https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a dumb question, but why dont you use:

```
width:100%;
padding-right:4em;
```

just like that?

Comment: If I want the max-width of the text to be 900px, a padding 4em would make the text wider than that on large screens.

Comment: Oh didnt get what you need... so use javascript to coumpute that from your element width :) if you dont know how i will provide solution for you